# Assign <a> tag with multiple IDs

Tags: php, html

Is there any way i am ble to assign multiple Id with a/hyperlink tag?

Is it possible? If so. How? Thanks.

This is what i want to do.

```
<a href="/directory/file.php?id='.$id1.' id2='.$id2.'">
```

Comment: should this tag `php` as well?

Comment: yes it should be in php

Comment: your Question needs an EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. add & in between id

```
echo '<a href="/directory/file.php?id='.$id1.'&id2='.$id2.'">';
```